# Ground state energy of Schrödinger energy functional for a potential $U(x) = -{1\over |x|^\alpha} $ with $\alpha >2$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, schwartz-space

For $\psi \in \mathscr S(\Bbb R^3) $ where $ \mathscr S $ is a Schwartz space, the Schrödinger energy functional is given by $$ \mathscr E(\psi) = ||\nabla \psi||_2^2 + \int_\Bbb {R^3} U|\psi|^2.$$
We also have that the ground state energy is given by $$ E_0=inf\{\mathscr E(\psi:\psi \in \mathscr S, ||\psi||=1\}.$$

I understand that $E_0$ is essentially the minimum energy of the system, however I am not clear on how one would compute this for a given potential.  For example I have been told that for $U(x) = -{1\over|x|^\alpha} $ where $\alpha >2$, $E_0=-\infty.$

How does one show this?

I started by writing $$ \mathscr E(\psi) =\int|\nabla\psi|^2d^3x-\int_\Bbb {R^3} {1\over|x|^\alpha} |\psi|^2d^3x$$ but am not sure on how to proceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Physically, the particle falls into the center for such a (strong) attractive potential. You should try a family of trial functions $\psi$ that are peaked close to $x=0$ and show that there is no lower bound on the functional.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to try the following family of functions
$$\psi_\epsilon(x)= c_\epsilon\frac{e^{-|x|^2}}{(|x|^2+\epsilon^2)^{(3-\alpha)/4}}  $$
with $c_\epsilon$ some normalization contant such that $||\psi_\epsilon||=1$. With that you can observe that $\mathscr{E}(\psi_\epsilon) \to -\infty$ for $\epsilon \to 0$. The reason is the potential term. While the kinetic term is some finite positive number. The potential term is diverging in particular, we have that

$$ -\int_{\mathbb R^3} \frac{1}{|x|^\alpha} |\psi_\epsilon|^2 \,d^3 x
= - 4\pi c_\epsilon^2 \int_0^\infty r^{2-\alpha} \frac{e^{-2 r^2}}{(r^2+\epsilon^2)^{(3-\alpha)/2} }dr = O(1) -  4\pi c_\epsilon^2 \underbrace{\int_0^1  \frac{r^{2-\alpha}}{(r^2+\epsilon^2)^{(3-\alpha)/2} }dr}_{\sim |\log \epsilon|}$$
such that we find that the infimum is  $-\infty$.

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, i don't quite follow the second step - does the integral only go from 0 $ \rightarrow $ 1 because the exponential term is suppressed for large r?  Also doesn't $ -4 \pi c_\epsilon ^2 ( log|\epsilon|)$ give + $\infty$?

Comment: I messed up the absolute value sign for the log. Regarding the question about the limit of the integral: The statement should be read that the integral to the left minus the integral to the right is a value of order one. That this the case indeed heavily depends on the fact that the integral does not do anything funny at large $r$ due to the exponential factor.